# Test a collection for equality or equivalence in Pester

Tags: powershell, pester

In nUnit, we can do something like this:

```
Expect(actualColleciton, EquivalentTo(expectedCollection));
```

and

```
Expect(actualCollection, EqualTo(expectedCollection));
```

Is there an equivalent in Pester?

I know I can do

```
$actualCollection | Should Be $expectedCollection
```

but it does NOT behave as you would expect.

Am I using the right syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to compare the contents of your collection, not the pointer/address to the collection.

I think you could inspire from something like:

```
$a1=@(1,2,3,4,5)
$b1=@(1,2,3,4,5,6)
$ret = (Compare-Object $a1 $b1).InputObject

if ($ret)
{
"different"
}
else
{
"same"
}
```

to do something like:

```
$ret = (Compare-Object $actualCollection $expectedCollection).InputObject
$ret | Should Be $null
```

where $null indicates the lists are the same.

Comment: Oooh, great suggestion!

I am changing the test to this:
```
    $result = Compare-Object $expectedScripts $ScriptsToRun

    $result | Should BeNullOrEmpty
```

Reason being, if it's wrong, and it's NOT null, you get output like this:
```
alue to be empty but it was {@{InputObject=LoadRoomsLegacy; SideIndicator=<=}}
```

Not ideal but gives you a good indication of what went wrong.